# Should I have two primary keys referencing each other?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

```
CREATE TABLE1 (
   ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   FOREIGN KEY ID REFERENCES TABLE2 (ID)
)

CREATE TABLE2 (
   ID INT NOT NULL,
   OTHER INT NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (ID, OTHER)
   FOREIGN KEY ID REFERENCES TABLE1 (ID)
)
```

Table 1 and Table 2 are big tables containing separate sets of information.
They have a one-to-one relationship requiring full participation from both sides. Where should I put the foreign key statement? In Table1, Table2, or both? And why?

Comment: Why aren't they one table? They are *logically* one table,why not physically? It would make everything easier.

Comment: I am creating tables for existing data from csv files. It is the way it's been provided to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing particularly wrong with doing it, however you should put the foreign key in *both* tables. That means when you insert new values you'll have to start a transaction, do both inserts, then commit the transaction.

I would strongly recommend merging the tables into one table. It will make everything easier.

Answer (score 0):

Id to id relationship is considered . This is a great trick in implementation .